# При отправки письма, через mailkit, меняется MessageId

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mailkit

На gmail работает все отлично, а при отправки с outlook меняется `MessageId`. Я пишу что то вроде такого :

```
    using var client = new SmtpClient();
await client.ConnectAsync(context.SmtpServer, context.SmtpPort, false, ct);
client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

await client.AuthenticateAsync(context.Email, context.Password, ct);
await client.SendAsync(message, ct);
    await client.DisconnectAsync(true, ct);

var uids = await mailFolder.SearchAsync(SearchQuery.SentSince(message.Date.DateTime), 

    ct);
 var messageSummary = (await mailFolder.FetchAsync(uids, MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Flags, ct)).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Envelope.MessageId == message.MessageId);
```

То есть мне надо получить потом это сообщение и кешировать его. Но он не находит messageSummary, так как в `.Envelope.MessageId` лежит другой айди, нежели в `message.MessageId` видно при отправке оутлук его меняет. Как это обойти или что я делю не так?